# Solution to Node js / Angular js - CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I found that making a ping to google cloud (or any web server you are using) every 5 minutes, so the database connection does not fall asleep is one the solution to the problem when lies on the server side.

Comment: Did you submit your question too early?

Comment: While it's perfectly acceptable to self-answer, it really should be done as an answer. Playact the question if you have to. (for more info, see: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: No, I just couldn't add comment to a similar problem and web page suggest to post a self-answer thread and voila

Comment: Thanks @NightShadeQueen